# How do I grant permission to a google service account to list all projects using terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, service-accounts

We're using terraform to manage our service accounts with google and big query. In order to list datasets and tables in our projects, we've elected to query a schema table using a service account:

```
select * from region-us.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE
```

This currently works, but only shows us tables from the project that this service account has access to. We'd like to see tables and datasets from across the organization, not just in the current project. Can Terraform grant read access to all projects in an organization?

I don't have much experience with terraform so any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Terraform to grant read access to all projects in an organization using the [`google_organization_iam_binding`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_organization_iam#google_organization_iam_binding) resource. This resource allows you to specify a role and a list of members to be granted that role within the organization.

You likely want to grant the `roles/bigquery.dataViewer` role to your service account which would give it read access to all projects in the organization:

```
resource "google_organization_iam_binding" "read" {
  role    = "roles/bigquery.dataViewer"
  members = ["serviceAccount:your-service-account@example.com"]
  org_id  = "1234567890"
}
```